# How to ensure a single instance of a core data entity

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I have an iPhone application and I would like to maintain profile information of the user.
I also have a list of friends.

The information fields contained in the profile are identical to that of a friend.

I have a core data entity for a friend.

Should I make a separate entity for the profile or just use the friend entity.

If I use a separate entity, how do I ensure there is only 1 instance of the profile.

If I use the friend entity, how do I make sure that the profile info does not show up when I fetch a list of friends for the friend table view.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should perhaps rethink your naming conventions to make it easier to visualise your object model.

There way I see it, you have an entity called 'Member' with all the properties you currently have, plus a many to many "isFriend" relationship to itself.

This way, any 'friend' can be a 'profile', and any 'profile' can be a 'friend'. It will also make it very straight forward for you to instantiate a 'Member' object and pull all of its 'friends'.

As for making sure there is only one instance of the profile, you will need a unique identifier for each instance - without having much of a background on what you are trying to achieve, I'd suggest you think about having a username or email address field which you will be able to use as parameter to perform a fetchRequest and see if you get any existing hits before allowing a member to register/create a new profile.

Comment: OK! Thanks. How do I make a fetch request based on the fields. eg. Fetch everything without name="MY NAME" (my profile). So i can populate a list of only friends?

Comment: Here's roughly how you would do it if you had a myName string with the name you DON'T want fetched - `NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init]; NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name != %@)", myName]; [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate]; NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Member" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];NSError *error;NSArray *arrayOfObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];`

Answer (score 0):

how about you make a single table with attributes like

```
Name (NSString)
...
//your desired attributes which are common to both
isFriend (BOOL)//to keep track of profile type
```

in this way you don't need to make two entity.